# How to debug code with std::optional or std::variant?

Tags: c++, gdb, lldb, c++17, pretty-print

It doesn't matter if I use libc++, libstdc++ neither gdb nor lldb can visualise `std::optional` or `std::variant`. I have googled a little but I didn't come across an obvious solution.

Have I missed any pretty-printers?

Comment: My gdb can tell me this: "foo = std::experimental::optional<int> [no contained value]" for a `optional<int> foo;`. `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12.1` and `g++ (GCC) 6.3.0` (test code compiled with `-ggdb`)

Comment: Ah. I will test c++14 instead. Maybe the libstdc++ pretty printer is bound to namespace experimental.

Comment: I would guess that your optional is storage for T, then a bool byte, or vice versa.  It shouldn't be hard to teach your debugger to read that...